# What does $variable ?: [] do?

Tags: php

```
$variable ?: []
```

What does it do? It's a ternary operator but looks a bit different and I don't know what [] means. Perhabs it's shorthand array of 5.4 and creates an empty array?

Comment: This code will throw an `E_NOTICE` if `$variable` is not set. So I would say it's better to test `if (!isset($variable)) { $variable = array(); }`.

Comment: I would not say this is a dup. The dup question specifies `?` and `:`, this question is when `?:` are together with no if true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is shorthand for:

```
if ($variable) {
    // nothing
} else {
    $variable = array();
}
```

`[]` is PHP 5.4 shorthand for `array()`

Comment: If you're going to expand it, wouldn't it make more sense as: `if(!$variable) $variable = array()`?

Comment: That depends on how strict you want to expand it. I'll stick with my interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

It means:

If `$variable` has a value then use that value, otherwise use an empty array.

The `[]` syntax is PHP 5.4 shorthand syntax for an empty array.
PHP 5.3 and earlier would write it as `array()`.

In other words, yep, your guess in the question about what it does is pretty much exactly right.