# Need php pdo implode arrays and insert multiple rows in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, implode

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629022/how-to-insert-an-array-into-a-single-mysql-prepared-statement-w-php-and-pdo) ([How to insert an array into a single MySQL Prepared statement w/ PHP and PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629022/how-to-insert-an-array-into-a-single-mysql-prepared-statement-w-php-and-pdo)) information trying to insert multiple rows.

Input (multiple rows)

```
<input type="text" name="date_day[]">
<input type="text" name="date_day[]">    

<input type="text" name="amount[]">
<input type="text" name="amount[]">
```

Get values from input

```
$date_day = $_POST['date_day'];
print_r($date_day);
echo ' date_day with print_r<br>';
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
print_r($amount);
echo ' amount with print_r<br>';
```

As a result of print_r can see

Array ( [0] => 22 [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629022/how-to-insert-an-array-into-a-single-mysql-prepared-statement-w-php-and-pdo) => 23 ) date_day with print_r

Array ( [0] => 45 [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629022/how-to-insert-an-array-into-a-single-mysql-prepared-statement-w-php-and-pdo) => 65 ) amount with print_r

Then from two arrays want to create one array

```
$data = array_combine($date_day,$amount);
```

Then insert code

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 2_1_journal (TransactionPartnerNameOrDescription, DocumentName) VALUES ";
$insertQuery = array();
$insertData = array();
foreach ($data as $row) {
$insertQuery[] = '(?, ?)';
$insertData[] = $amount;
$insertData[] = $row;
}

if (!empty($insertQuery)) {
$sql .= implode(', ', $insertQuery);
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($insertData);
}
```

As a result in:

column TransactionPartnerNameOrDescription are inserted two rows with word Array

column DocumentName are inserted two rows with 45 and 65 (`$amount` array)

Please advice why in column TransactionPartnerNameOrDescription instead of array values is inserted word Array?

I suppose it is related with this code

```
$insertQuery = array();
$insertData = array();
foreach ($data as $row) {
$insertQuery[] = '(?, ?)';
$insertData[] = $amount;
$insertData[] = $row;
```

but I do not understand what the each line does... may be some link with explanations or similar examples

Latter instead of `$data = array_combine($date_day,$amount);` used `$data = array_merge($date_day,$amount);`.

In this case get four rows for column Document name with values 22, 23, 45, 46. And word Array for TransactionPartnerNameOrDescription column

**Update**
Actually things are more simple than seems at first sight

Here is code to insert more values (as sample for someone else; may be will be useful)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 2_1_journal (RecordDay, RecordMonth, RecordYear, Amount) VALUES ";
$insertQuery = array();
$insertData = array();
foreach ($_POST['date_day'] as $i => $date_day) {
$insertQuery[] = '(?, ?, ?, ?)';
$insertData[] = $date_day;
$insertData[] = $_POST['date_month'][$i];
$insertData[] = $_POST['date_year'][$i];
$insertData[] = $_POST['amount'][$i];
}
```

**One more question**

Please, advice what means (does)

```
$insertQuery = array();
$insertData = array();
```

Does it simply define/set that $insertQuery and $insertData both are arrays?

Something related is here [What does $variable ?: [] do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108391/what-does-variable-do) but for me not fully understandable. Please, advice

Comment: rather from this: `$data = array_combine($date_day,$amount);`

Comment: Latter instead of $data = array_combine($date_day,$amount); used $data = array_merge($date_day,$amount);. In this case get four rows for column Document name with values 22, 23, 45, 46. And word Array for TransactionPartnerNameOrDescription column

Comment: How come that amount being stored into field named `TransactionPartnerNameOrDescription`, and date - into `DocumentName`. Field names looks quite inconsistent

Comment: Numbers in table name also smells of some delusion

Comment: Field names are because I took example and used for my tables. Table names were already created. I only tried the example to get it work. When will get to work, then will change names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($_POST['date_day'] as $i => $date_day) {
    $insertQuery[] = '(?, ?)';
    $insertData[] = $_POST['amount'][$i];
    $insertData[] = $date_day;
}
```

> Does it simply define/set that $insertQuery and $insertData both are arrays?

Yes.

And `[]` is a shorthand for `array()` since PHP 5.4, so you can make it

```
$insertQuery = [];
$insertData = [];
```

or

```
$insertQuery = array();
$insertData = [];
```

or

```
$insertQuery = $insertData = [];
```

Comment: Thank you. Is some link available with information about the code in answer? As I understand the first ? is bind with $insertData[] = $date_day; and the second ? is bind with $insertData[] = $_POST['amount'][$i]; Actually I need to insert in more columns. Would need to change foreach ($_POST['date_day'] as $i => $date_day) {.... but how....